# Equals sign added to output when I turn code into a function

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, xetex

I'm new-ish to TeX, so if I'm approaching things completely wrong and there's a better way to go about it, please let me know. I already use the tikz package to draw some charts and visuals in my document, so that's why I chose using pgf here.

I need to calculate and present some numbers as percentages, so I put together the following, which outputs what I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\CurrentMeasureValue{0.7127625}
\newcommand\PercentValue{}

\begin{document}
    \pgfmathparse{100*\CurrentMeasureValue}
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}{\PercentValue}
    \PercentValue\%
\end{document}
```

The output from this is `71.28%`.

However, I need to use this multiple times, so I'm trying to turn it into a macro, but when I do so, I end up with an equals sign in front of the output that I want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\CurrentMeasureValue{0.7127625}
\newcommand\PercentValue{}

\newcommand\PercentTwoDecimal[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{100*#1}%
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}{\renewcommand\PercentValue}\%%
}

\begin{document}
    \PercentTwoDecimal{\CurrentMeasureValue}
\end{document}
```

The output from this is `=71.28%`. I'm using the output as a label on a graph, so I don't want the equals sign. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\renewcommand` command cannot be included in the definition of `\PercentTwoDecimal`, and type `\PercentValue` before `\%`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\CurrentMeasureValue{0.7127625}
\newcommand\PercentValue{}

\newcommand\PercentTwoDecimal[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{100*#1}%
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}{\PercentValue} % Removed the \renewcommand
    \PercentValue\%} % Inserted \PercentValue before \%

\begin{document}
    \PercentTwoDecimal{\CurrentMeasureValue}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I guess I'm not understanding `\renewcommand` correctly then, I'll do some more reading on it.